# CellContentClicked event of DataGridView is being automatically called again and again

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my Main Form I have given 5 different Forms are linked through the different buttons click through it and in the MainForm I have a DataGridView, populated by SQL Server, where I have added a new column for edit button for each row.

The `edit` Button, opens a new Form with the data already present in the database with the help of `CellContentClick` event but while clicking the `cancel` Button in the Form for the first time it is closing the Form in 1 time. If I click the other Form's Button and clicking the `edit` Button on that DataGridView again after which if I try to cancel the new Form opened it is reopening the Form for 2 times.
Repetition of same procedure will reopen the form with increment of 1 every time.

The code for `CellContentClick` event:

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (lblHeader.Text == "MailBox Configuration")
        {
            GlobalName.Name = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
            AddConfigForm.DisplayData(conStr);
            if (GlobalRefresh.Refresh == true)
            {
                GlobalRefresh.Refresh = false;
                btnMailboxConfigPage_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }

        if (lblHeader.Text == "Client Master")
        {
            GlobalId.Id = int.Parse(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
            ClientForm.DisplayData(conStr);
            if (GlobalRefresh.Refresh == true)
            {
                GlobalRefresh.Refresh = false;
                btnClientPage_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: clicking the cancel button is re-running the same code, every time with the incrementation of 1 extra time

Comment: So is it resolved? It's not aparent, how do you declare your edit forms - I suppose those would be `AddConfigForm` and `ClientForm`. You change GlobalRefresh.Refresh after first click, that might be where it gets wrong. Perhaps it could be an issue with form instances. Difficult to say without all related code.